# Unescape Special Characters in Process builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, process-builder, chatter, chatter-feed

I am having a text field in an object whose value is posted on chatter using Process Builder.
If one record contains special character **`&`**, then the chatter post comes like **`&amp;`**

Is there any way to unescape HTML characters in process builder ?